# Build a command dynamically

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar, string

I'm working on a script and I need to build the `tar` command dynamically.

Here are two examples to illustrate what I'm trying to do :

```
#!/bin/bash

TAR_ME="/tmp"

EXCLUDE=("/tmp/hello hello" "/tmp/systemd*" "/tmp/Temp*")
_tar="tar "`printf -- '--exclude="%s" ' "${EXCLUDE[@]}"`" -zcf tmp.tar.gz"
echo COMMAND: "${_tar}"
${_tar} "$TAR_ME"

echo -e "\n\nNEXT:\n\n"

EXCLUDE=("--exclude=/tmp/hello\ hello" "--exclude=/tmp/systemd*" "--exclude=/tmp/Temp*")
_tar="tar "`printf -- '%s ' "${EXCLUDE[@]}"`" -zcf test.tar.gz"
echo COMMAND: "${_tar}"
${_tar} "$TAR_ME"
```

I want to be able to use `_tar` as a command, I've been able to make it work with classic path, but I need it to work with spaces in folders' name.
And every single time I got errors that look like :

```
COMMAND: tar --exclude="/tmp/hello hello" --exclude="/tmp/systemd*" --exclude="/tmp/Temp*"  -zcf tmp.tar.gz /tmp
tar: hello": Cannot stat: No such file or directory

COMMAND: tar --exclude=/tmp/hello\ hello --exclude=/tmp/systemd* --exclude=/tmp/Temp*  -zcf test.tar.gz 
tar: hello: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

Just one thing you need to know, I need my script to work on very old machines, meaning I can't use last bash features.

Comment: I believe the --exclude option can only accept a single string after it.  You can have multiple --exclude statements though.  Maybe try "--exclude=/tmp/hello --exclude=hello"   Oops.  Nevermind.  I misunderstood.

Comment: @LewisM I think OP want to exclude directory "/tmp/hello hello" (yes, with a space.

Comment: @ShellCode what about quoting all exclude, e.g. "--exclude=/tmp/hello hello"

Comment: Yeah.  That's why I put the Oops statement later.  :)

Comment: How about putting `eval` in front of the execution?

Comment: Does your unspecified very old machine even have bash? Are you sure you're looking explicitly for a bash script or do you actually need "normal vanilla" shell?

Comment: Yep bash is ok, but it has to be compatible with old bash versions

Comment: @pipe The shell you mean is `sh`, the Bourne shell. But if by "normal vanilla" you mean most standard shell, it's `posh`, A shell implementing the current POSIX specification.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't try to make an executable string.  Instead build the arguments in an array and use that when calling `tar` (you are already using an array properly for `EXCLUDE`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

directory=/tmp

exclude=( "hello hello" "systemd*" "Temp*" )

# Now build the list of "--exclude" options from the "exclude" array:
for elem in "${exclude[@]}"; do
    exclude_opts+=( --exclude="$directory/$elem" )
done

# Run tar
tar -cz -f tmp.tar.gz "${exclude_opts[@]}" "$directory"
```

With `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

directory=/tmp

set -- "hello hello" "systemd*" "Temp*"

# Now build the list of "--exclude" options from the "$@" list
# (overwriting the values in $@ while doing so):
for elem do
    set -- "$@" --exclude="$directory/$elem"
    shift
done

# Run tar
tar -cz -f tmp.tar.gz "$@" "$directory"
```

Note the quoting of `$@` in the `sh` code and of both `${exclude[@]}` and `${exclude_opts[@]}` in the `bash` code.  This ensures that the lists are expanded to individually quoted elements.

Related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 2):

```
mix(){
        p=$1; shift; q=$1; shift; c=
        i=1; for a; do c="$c $q \"\${$i}\""; i=$((i+1)); done
        eval "${p%\%*}$c${p#*\%}"
}
mix 'tar % -zcf tmp.tar.gz' --exclude "/tmp/hello hello" "/tmp/systemd*" "/tmp/Temp*"

EXCLUDE=("/tmp/hello hello" "/tmp/systemd*" "/tmp/Temp*")
mix 'tar % -zcf tmp.tar.gz' --exclude "${EXCLUDE[@]}"
```

Extending the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531453/10306503).
This doesn't rely on any bashisms, it will also work fine with debian's `/bin/sh`, and with `busybox`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I don't really like the eval, it's quite dangerous... Moreover, this code is quite hard to understand, don't you have something easier ? :/ The script will be distributed so I have to keep it as simple as possible...

Comment: It's not dangerous. Run it with `set -x`. What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Also, read the original answer on stackoverflow. It includes a demo.

Comment: It works quite well though... Waiting to see if anybody has a cleaner answer, otherwise I will accept yours. Maybe there is nothing wrong with that code, but every time I see an eval, I'm afraid the code could lead to command injection, that's why I try to avoid it

Comment: I've updated the answer with a fix for indexes > 9. You can replace the eval with an echo to see what's actually getting (the eval doesn't see the filenames)